# How to handle locked/disabled user accounts with Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible?

Tags: perl, authentication, dancer

I'm currently migrating a CGI application to Dancer2. I previously used a "hand-crafted" authentication mechanism using MySQL and a user table with the attributes `email`, `password`, and a `state`. The `state` indicates whether the account is `active` or `locked`. `locked` means the account is disabled (logically deleted).

I also have tables `roles` and `user_roles` to implement my two roles: admin and user.

Everything works like a charm, with one exception:

With my old "hand-crafted" mechanism I was able to *lock* users, i.e. logically delete them without removing them from the database. A login was only successful if email and hash_of(password) matched *and* the account was not locked.

How do I implement that with [`Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible) and [`Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database)?

I hoped that the hook [`after_authenticate_user`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#after_authenticate_user) could return `true` or `false` to overwrite the result of `authenticate_user`, but that is not the case. At least, it is not documented.

One thing I thought of was to have an additional role `active` and then – for every route – `require_role active` instead of just `require_login`.

So my question is: How can I make `Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible` consider only `active` users?

Comment: I don't see why someone would downvote your question. It's well-written, shows _some_ research (we coulld argue that reading the source shouldn't be expected, or there was no point in asking at all), it clearly states what you want to do and why, and having a code sample is not relevant here.

Comment: I created a ticket to move this into the docs: https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database/issues/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Borodin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746864/how-to-handle-locked-disabled-user-accounts-with-dancer2pluginauthextensib#comment80440684_46746987) to create a view and use that as the user table. I've done some testing and can say that that is indeed the easiest way to achieve this.

**Warning**: because of the nature of views, this makes it impossible for the application to modify or add users!

Consider the following [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2) application. I started with the `dancer2` create script.

```
$ dancer2 gen -a Foo
$ cd Foo
```

I created the following simple sqlite database.

```
$ echo "
CREATE TABLE users (
    id       INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    disabled TIMESTAMP   NULL
);

CREATE VIEW active_users (id, username, password) AS
    SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE disabled IS NULL;

INSERT INTO users ( username, password, disabled )
VALUES  ( 'foo', 'test', null),
        ( 'bar', 'test', '2017-10-01 10:10:10');
" | sqlite3 foo.sqlite
```

There is only a `users` table with the default columns as suggested by the plugin, plus a column `disabled`, which can be `NULL` or a timestamp. I thought it would be easier to illustrate with *disabled* than with *active*.

Then I made the following changes to `lib/Foo.pm`. All of this is basically from the documentation of [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible) and [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database).

```
package Foo;
use Dancer2;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Database;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index' => { 'title' => 'Foo' };
};

get '/users' => require_login sub {
    my $user = logged_in_user;
    return "Hi there, $user->{username}";
};

true;
```

Next, the plugins needed to go into the config. Edit `config.yml` and replace it with this.

```
appname: "Foo"
layout: "main"
charset: "UTF-8"
template: "simple"
engines:
  session:
    Simple:
      cookie_name: testapp.session

# this part is interesting
plugins:
    Auth::Extensible:
        realms:
            users:
                provider: 'Database'

############### here we set the view
                users_table: 'active_users'
    Database:
        driver: 'SQLite'
        database: 'foo.sqlite'
        on_connect_do: ['PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON']
        dbi_params:
            PrintError: 0
            RaiseError: 1
```

Now we're all set to try.

```
$ plackup bin/app.psgi
HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:5000/
```

Visit http://localhost:5000/users in your browser. You'll see the default login form.

[image: login page]

Enter `foo` and `test`. This should work, and you should see the `/users` route. (Or not, as in my case, where the redirect seems to be broken...).

[image: foo is logged in]

Now go to http://localhost:5000/logout to get rid of foo's cookie and open http://localhost:5000/users again. This time, enter `bar` and `test`.

You will see that the login does not work.

[image: bar cannot log in]

To make a counter-test, replace the `users_table` in `config.yml` and restart the app.

```
# config.yml
                users_table: 'users'
```

Now the user `foo` will be able to log in.

This method is not only easy to implement, it should also by far be the way with the highest performance, as the database handles all the logic (and has most likely already cached it).

Your application, and especially the authentication plugin, do not need to know about the existence of the *active* or *disabled* fields at all. They don't need to care. Stuff will just work.

Comment: You might want to do something fancy to allow active user names that are duplicates of disabled ones. Perhaps a constraint on multiple columns? `CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (username, disabled)` may work but it's not very pretty.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure that allowing that would be such a good idea. Then the user is not unique any more. For an audit, that might be relevant.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for both of your great answers. You even submitted a ticket for D2's FAQ. I think as a first shot I'll use the solution with the view because that's easier to implement. For the long term I'll perhaps dig deeper and write my own Provider which fully integrates the `state` column. My application also has an admin page with the possibility to lock and unlock users, so it would be cool if the [`update_user`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#update_user) function would work (including the `state` column) seamlessly.

Comment: @PerlDuck just remember that you cannot use the view for updating or adding users. That will fail because of the nature of views in databases. If you go with the alternative and create a provider, I don't think a lot of work is needed to for adding or updating. The state column is just another value that can be passed to `update_user` or `create_user`.

Comment: _Re: your warning about non-updateable views:_ It actually _is_ possible to insert into a view but certain restrictions apply. I'm currently not sure whether they apply to my current design. Perhaps I can use `update_user` for the VIEW (all attributes except `state`) and then update the `state` in the TABLE with a separate SQL statement. However, I already have the statemtents to update and create users, and I can use them instead of the `update_user` call.

Comment: @PerlDuck maybe. In my example it doesn't work. _users provider threw error: DBD::SQLite::db do failed: cannot modify active_users because it is a view at /home/simbabque/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.4/lib/site_perl/5.18.4/Dancer/Plugin/Database/Core/Handle.pm line 310._

Comment: Yes, sometimes it works, sometimes not. I haven't used it for years and cannot remember the exact prerequisites. Perhaps MySQL is more tolerant than SQLite in this case.

Comment: Something else: you wrote _"Or not, as in my case, where the redirect [to the `/users` route] seems to be broken...)."_ I noticed the very same! Instead of redirecting to `/...` it redirects to `//...`. At first I thought I made something wrong or had an additional leading `/` somewhere but that is not the case. I consider this a bug.

Comment: @PerlDuck yes. I was going to report it as well. Later today.

Comment: @PerlDuck there is already a ticket for that problem: https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible/issues/74 and someone also already submitted a PR two months ago, but it hasn't been merged. I'll bug them about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database](http://ttps://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database) and wrap the `get_user_details` method to check if the user is active or not.

Consider the same application I used [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46750569/1331451). Add the following class.

```
package Provider::Database::ActiveOnly;

use Moo;
extends 'Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database';

around 'get_user_details' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    # do nothing if we there was no user
    my $user = $self->$orig(@_) or return;

    # do nothing if the user is disabled
    return if $user->{disabled};

    return $user;
};

1;
```

The code is straightforward. After a user gets looked up, we have have the user data, so we can check the `disabled` column. If there is a anything in it, the user was disabled, and we abort.

You also need to make the following changes to the `config.yml`.

```
# config.yml
plugins:
    Auth::Extensible:
        realms:
            users:
                provider: 'Provider::Database::ActiveOnly'
                users_table: 'users'
```

Now the application should behave exactly as in the other answer.

---

To understand why this works we need to look at the source. The authenticating happens in [`authenticate_user`](https://metacpan.org/source/HORNBURG/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database-0.620/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible/Provider/Database.pm#L327). Initially I thought that's what ought to be replaced, but this solution is smarter, because we only need to fetch the user data once.

The `authenticate_user` method [fetches the user data](https://metacpan.org/source/HORNBURG/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database-0.620/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible/Provider/Database.pm#L333) with [the `get_user_details` method](https://metacpan.org/source/HORNBURG/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database-0.620/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible/Provider/Database.pm#L372), so we can hook in there. Our [`around` wrapper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo#around) will inject the check for the activeness of the user transparently, and the rest of the code doesn't even know there is a difference.

Inactive users will not show up in any interaction related to Plugin::Auth::Extensible.

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a *view* on the user table which simply excludes the locked records, and get the authentication to work off that? `DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View` is a subclass of `DBIx::Class::ResultSource` so the calling code shouldn't know any different, but you know far more about Dancer than I.

Comment: @Borodin that sounds like a great idea. I didn't think about it. If that thing uses DBIC under the hood. If not, a regular view would work too. I like it.

Comment: I'm going to try this out @Borodin. If it works out, we can PR it into the docs.

Comment: "PR" == *patch request*? Yes that sounds great. I was just looking at `Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database` which appears to be database agnostic. To be honest, for no particular reason I thought Dancer was inextricably tied with DBIC, but as you say it will work either way. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: It's _pull request_. But you got the idea, yes. (Maybe you want to participate in https://hacktoberfest.digitalocean.com/, and the http://cpan-prc.org/?) Dancer is not at all tied with DBIC. I think they use it in the examples, and it works well together, but you can have plain DBI without problems. I used to be closer to the Dancer people because one of them was in my local Perl monger group, but I since moved and I use Catalyst at $work. I want to do more Dancer. The community is awesome and I have friends there.

Comment: I've been looking at the CPAN PRC but how does it work? I've registered to receive messages, but the history shows only ten messages in Jan/Feb and nothing since. How do you pick something to work on, and how do you know someone else isn't already working on it?

Comment: @Borodin the mailing list is only for discussion. You need to write Neil an email saying you'd like to participate and include your github account name. If you do that now, you can ask for an assignment for this month. You will then receive a new assignment on every 1st of the month and you'll have that month to complete at least one PR. When you're done, you mail Neil "I'm done" and that's it. The idea is that you don't pick. The challenge is that the dice pick for you. And then you end up with weird things you've never heard of before. It's fun actually. :)

Comment: Okay. I assume you mean Neil Bowers? How do you get an assignment that's suited to you? Where is all this described? There seems to be very little explanation, but I'm likely being dumb :)

Comment: @Borodin I've written an answer with the view idea. It's really neat.

Comment: @Borodin and here's the alternative. I'm not sure which one is better. Both have pros and cons. But I'll go to bed now and let PerlDuck figure out what they like more.

Comment: Also I just realised https://metacpan.org/release/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-DBIC was my first assigned in the PRC. Related to the DBIC and D2 discussion.

Comment: When watching the source of [`authenticate_user`](https://metacpan.org/source/HORNBURG/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database-0.620/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible/Provider/Database.pm#L327) I saw a third approach: simply set the password for locked users to an empty string. The downside is that unlocking involves a password-reset.

Comment: @Borodin I've prepared a PR to add this to the documentation of the database provider, and your name came up. Please feel free to review it: https://github.com/simbabque/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-Provider-Database/commit/baad8e1dc7ed00ae9a85bbd5c0a734b6a2854ee7

Comment: @PerlDuck please feel free to also review my commit linked in the above comment before I create a PR.

Comment: I've submitted that PR now.